# Excel copy cell value when row does not contain certain text

Tags: excel

I'm looking to avoid VBA if possible and manipulate some Excel data.

I have data with one column of values, containing blanks and numbers. For example column A: 1, 5,  , 2. And another column containing text, for example column B: Include, exclude, include, exclude. Not sure how to put a table here, but basically:

1 include
5 exclude
include
2 exclude

I am looking to (in any order) copy data to a new column that both does not contain the word "exclude" in its row and does not contain blank data in its cell.

To get rid of blanks I use

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AL$2:AL$3309,SMALL(IF(AL$2:AL$3309<>"",ROW(AL$2:AL$3309)-ROW(AL$2)+1),ROWS(AW$2:AW2))),"")
```

where AW is where I want copied values and AL is where the values and blanks are. Data in rows 2 through 3309.

How can I also copy only data that does not include the text "exclude" in its row? (There is a separate column for each value with a text value) If this can be done in one function, great! If not, that is fine.

Thank you!

As a small separate issue, is there a way to auto detect the last value in a column? So that for my formula, instead of updating every instance of 3309 to 3310 if I were to add another row of data, I could just say "last row containing data" if that makes sense.